# What are differences between Chrome on Android and Desktop Chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, webkit, cross-browser

I know both use the same webkit version (537.36) and both use the same javascript engine (V8), but are there any other major differences between them?

I have a webapp with automated tests for desktop Chrome but nothing for Chrome on Android. I'm trying to decide if I know it works on desktop Chrome do I need to go through the trouble of testing it on Chrome on Android, or are they similar enough that I should have confidence it works on both.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main difference is that Android don't have Flash because of the HTML5 implementation, and also there's a lot of different screen sizes and users don't like to zoom in and out a pan and zoom again, so the best you can do is to create a web designed for mobile devices.

On the other hand, if your site is mainly HTML and Javascript, will work 100% on mobile Chrome. I have a HTML5 game and works equal in desktop and mobile.

Also, you can download the Android SDK and test your site in a bunch of different Android versions and screen sizes with the AVD, is like an official Android emulator.