# Button onclick delete another browser window

Tags: javascript, html, window, intervals

I have two web pages.
First.html:

```
<script> window.onload = function(){ setTimeout(loadAfterTime, 3000) }; function loadAfterTime() { my_window = window.open("Second.html", "","status=1,width=100%,height=100%");}
this.window = previous_window ;
 </script>
```

Second.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
function closepopup()
   {
      if(false == previous_window.closed)
      {
         previous_window.close ();
      }
      else
      {
         alert('Window already closed!');
      }
   }
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="closepopup();">
            Close
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

If we load first.html in a browser, after 3 seconds of load, the JavaScript will make a browser window with the URL set into Second.html.
I have added a button in the second.html file.
If we press that button, I want to delete/remove the previous browser window (first.html).
The `window.open` is working button `window.close` is not.
Please help.
Also, the code should perfectly work on mobile devices(Latest Chrome app on Android and IOS).
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Was the first window opened by a script?  If not, you won't be able to close it.  See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close).  However if it was opened by script you could use the standard `window.opener.close()` instead of your own `previous_window` variable.

Answer (score 0):

First.html

```
<script> 
window.onload = setTimeout(loadAfterTime, 3000);
function loadAfterTime()
{
    window.open("Second.html","","status=1,width=100%,height=100%");
}
</script>
```

Second.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function closepopup()
{
    if(window.opener)
    {
        window.opener.close();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Window already closed!");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="closepopup();">Close</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which browser are you using ?

Comment: also check if popup is being blocked

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Pop-ups are not blocked.

Comment: is Second.html window opening after you open First.html?

Comment: I just opened first.html and the JavaScript itself opened second.html

Comment: yes thats how it should work. Are you able to close First.html by clicking close button on Second.html window ?

Comment: no. I made my website for only mobile visitors. So please give a code, which supports mobile devices. I'll only check this code on mobile devices.

Comment: i just checked now , it works on mobile too , tell me what problem you are facing.

Comment: i guess the working remains the same whether you run it on computer or mobile, only the look changes.

Comment: Oh no! It's not.

Comment: i think it the working of your code depends on the browser and not the device. Also have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944522/what-are-differences-between-chrome-on-android-and-desktop-chrome

Comment: which browser did you used?

Comment: chrome for both desktop(Version 62.0.3202.89) and mobile(version 61.0.3163.98)

Comment: Do you have any idea on why it didn't worked for me?

Comment: I have tried resetting Chrome://flags in Android. But still no changes.

Comment: can you tell me exactly what is not working for you?